# When you twist your glass, the ice stays still

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws

When you twist your glass and the ice cube stays still, what causes that?

(Example: you put an ice cube in your glass, and then spin the glass to see the other side of the ice cube, but it won't spin with the glass, instead it stays still.)

Comment: The ice has inertia and low friction with the glass, so twirling the glass doesn't exert enough force on the ice to move it much.

Comment: In addition, the water around the ice has a low viscosity, and therefore doesn't transmit shear forces very well (which you apply when you twist the glass). If you did this with ice in honey, the ice would probably twist with the glass.

Comment: honey is much more solid than ice so probably

Comment: Honey isn't "more solid" than ice, in any sense. It's more viscous than water, but it's not solid.

Comment: yes sorry it is denser

Comment: But density has nothing to do with viscosity. Ethanol is less dense than water, but more viscous. Liquid mercury at 600 Kelvin is more dense than water, but less viscous.

Comment: @probably_someone: that looks like a answer....

Comment: @probably_someone So have you tried ice in a class of 600K mercury?

Comment: @JEB I have a feeling my coworkers might not appreciate that particular setup; I was just trying to find an example of a liquid that's more dense than water, with a lower viscosity. There are surprisingly few examples.

Comment: A more accessible example is cream and milk. Cream is clearly less dense, since it floats on milk, but it is obviously more viscous.

Comment: @probably_someone Having spilled a few pounds of mercury in a physics lab, and can verify it doesn't go over well with the coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

This is due tu the inertia of the water and ice cube in it and the relatively low viscosity of water which mediates a force between the glass and the water. Even though the water near the  glass will be dragged along a bit, it will take more than one rotation to transfer this motion to the water and ice inside the glass. When you rotate the glass constantly for a while, the water and ice will eventually follow this rotation due to the viscous force related to the glass movement. See [Newton's law of viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Newtonian_and_non-Newtonian_fluids).